# creating view with couchdb that does grouping and unique counting

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

hi I have documents like so

```
{ 
  domains: "domain1.com", 
  ip: "192.168.0.1" 
}
```

documents may have different or duplicate domains/ips

I want a view that give me a list of

domain1 => unique ip count for that domain
domain2 => unique ip count for that domain
 
etc..

I know how to get a:

domain => ip count with this map/reduce:

```
 "map": "function(doc) { emit(doc.domains, 1) }",<br/>
 "reduce": "_sum"
```

and a group=true parameter

But I can't figure out how to to get a:

domain => unique ip count style list

cheers for any assistance, sorry for my english

Comment: I don't think it will work with *just* a map/reduce view, but if you combine it with a list function it should be trivial.

Comment: thanks it not matter to me if a list is involved, i have looked at that as well actually, just rather at a loss at how to accomplish it period at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Write a view with only a map function and no reduce function

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.domains) emit(doc.domains, doc.ip);
}
```

Then create a list function that counts the unique entries.

```
function(head, req) {
  var ips = new Array();
  while (row = getRow()) {
    if (ips.indexOf(row) != -1) { 
      ips.push(row.value);
    }
  }
  send(ips.length);
}
```

Warning: code not tested, might contain bugs.

Finally you call the list function on the map view with `key` set to the domain you want. Note that this solution won't perform very well if you have a large number of IPs per domain.

Answer (score 0):

As Kim said, it's nearly impossible (or maybe with a very tricky `reduce` function) to do the whole thing with CouchdDB's Map/Reduce.

However, you could do at least the deduplication part with Map/Reduce in order to get better performance than with Kim's solution.

So, first use a `map` to index (domain, ip) pairs (values are not important):

```
function(o) {
  emit([o.domain, o.ip], null);
}
```

Then `reduce` them with a builtin function:

```
_count
```

Now, use a `list` to count unique ips:

```
function(head, req) {
  var domains = {};
  while (row = getRow()) {
    var d = row.key[0];
    if (d in domains) {
      domains[d]++;
    } else {
      domains[d] = 1;
    }
  }
  send(JSON.stringify(domains));
}
```

When you call it, query it with `group=true`.

Note: I haven't tested the code of the list so you might have to slightly adapt it.